# AdMob with Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, admob, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2.

> ```
> Your system information:
>
> Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
> Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
> OS:
> Node Version: v6.2.2
> ```

I have just installed the Cordova plugin [cordova-admob-pro](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro
```

Then as per their instructions, I add the following code:

**app.ts**

```
import { AdMob } from 'ionic-native';
....
if (AdMob) AdMob.createBanner({
  adId: admobid.banner,
  position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
  isTesting: true,//comment this out before publishing the app
  autoShow: true
});
```

But, I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR in ./app/app.ts
> (138,23): error TS2339: Property 'AD_POSITION' does not exist on type 'typeof AdMob'.
> ```

When I follow the imported code, `AdMob` is defined in `admob.d.ts` in the plugin, but it doesn't have a `AD_POSITION`:

**admob.d.ts**

```
...
export declare class AdMob {
...
```

If anyone can advise what I am doing wrong, and how I can get a handle on `AD_POSITION`, I would appreciate it.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The problem is because the `Admob` in `ionic-native` does not have `AD_POSITION`, however, if I remove the import from `ionic-native`, I get:

> ```
> ERROR in ./app/app.ts
> (136,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AdMob'.
> ```

I see that `AD_POSITION` is in `plugins\cordova-plugin-admobpro\typescript\AdMob.d.ts`. So I gather, this is the one I should be using.  But how do I import this one?

**UPDATE**

This may be the problem. I am just testing it.

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is what I now have, but I still get the error below:

[image]

> ```
> ERROR in ./app/app.ts
> (136,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AdMob'.
> ```

So my problem is that I don't know how to import the '`AdMob`' from the plugin.

Comment: is this resolved?

Comment: I solved my issue by doing the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Bu not importing `AdMob`, and doing the following instead works:

`declare var AdMob: any;`

Answer (score 0):

**Adding AdMobPro In Ionic 2**

**Step 1:** Install AdMobPro plugin

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro

**Step 2:** Add Platform

> ionic cordova platform add android
> OR
>
> ionic cordova platform add ios

**Step 3:** Implement AdMob into your Ionic 2 project

*Banner Ads* :

we need to code it inside src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { AdMobPro } from '@ionic-native/admob-pro';

 constructor(private admob: AdMobPro,platform: Platform ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => { 

      this.admob.createBanner({ adId: 'ca-app-pub-............', adSize: 'SMART_BANNER', isTesting: false }).then(() => {
        this.admob.showBanner(8);
      }); 

    });
  }
```

we need to code it inside src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { AdMobPro } from '@ionic-native/admob-pro';

providers: [
    AdMobPro,
```

*Interstitial Ads* :

```
loadAd(){
   let options = {
    adId: 'ca-app-pub-5732334124058455/3403366048',
    isTesting: false
   };
    AdMob.prepareInterstitial(options)
         .then(() => {
           AdMob.showInterstitial();
         });
  };
```